# regex matching parsing

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have this patter `p` and want to use this pattern to find if it has any matching. This is in Python.

`p = "keyword" + ".*?(\d+(\.\d+)?[\s%]?[\w/]*)"
 found = re.findall(p, some_text)`

I have problem parsing this regex.

1. What is the first "?".

   I understand that ".*" matches any thing for 0  or more times. But not sure what the "?" does here.
2. It is weird to see nested capture group parenthesis. What does it do?
3. What is the "?" in `[\s%]?` regex?  I assume this is matching white space followed by "%". But not sure what the "?" does here.
4. What is the asterisk in `[\w/]*` regex? I assume this is matching any word character followed by forward slash. But not sure what the "*" does.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 2):

```
.*?(\d+(\.\d+)?[\s%]?[\w/]*)
```

1. `.*?` matches any character (except for line terminators)
   `*?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
2. 1st Capturing Group `(\d+(\.\d+)?[\s%]?[\w/]*)`
3. `\d+` matches a digit (equal to `[0-9]`) Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
4. 2nd Capturing Group `(\.\d+)?`
5. `\.` matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
6. `[\s%]?` Match a single character present in `\r` or `\n` or `\t` or `\f` or `\v`
7. `%` matches the character % literally (case sensitive)
8. `[\w/]*` , where `\w` Match a single character present in `a-zA-Z0-9_`
9. `/` matches the character / literally (case sensitive)

You can put your regex in [here](https://regex101.com/r/nPPWv4/4) and get the analysis at the right top of the site.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have a few more questions.

10. `[\s%]?` ---- What does the "?"  do here?


11. `[\w/\]*`   ----  What does the "*" do here?


12. This regex is working mostly for my purposes. But I need to also be able to extract number from a text like "KeyA: 5555\n KeyB:". I want to extract number 5555 in this case, but this regex extracts "5555\n KeyB". Do you know how to make a modification? Note that I still need to match things like % and forward slash (i.e. i cannot remove them from the regex)